How do I know if an error was handled in a .catch() block when using rtk-query middleware?
I use rtk-query and I have a mutation query. After the query is executed, some actions are performed in the .then() block and then the error is processed in .catch().
Also, a middleware is written that catches all errors of all queries in the project and displays them as notifications for the user.
The task is to determine inside the middleware whether the .catch() block was called or not and, based on this condition, perform some actions in the middleware.
I looked inside the action objects that the middleware gives me, but there is no hint of a .catch() block.
Is this even possible?

I don't know rtk-query in detail, but it sounds like that middleware runs before the promise is returned to the caller who might add .catch(). In that case, no, this is not possible. You'll need to refactor this to either a) pass options to the middleware instead of using .catch() or b) don't do the handling in the middleware at all and let each caller decide between adding the default error handler, a custom error handler, or no error handler at all.

@Bergi Got it. The idea was that if .catch() is called, then the error is handled in it and then there is no need to call the handler inside the middleware. Fortunately, react-toastify can accept toast id notifications, and I made it so that id=notification text, I did the same in the middleware, then at least they are not duplicated. But thanks anyway.
